# How do I slant a column header in excel? Not just the text angle, but the header rectangle as well?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I angle the text, the column rectangle doesn't slant.

Comment: Is this in a graph or just within the spreadsheet view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you angle the text, add a border (Format Cell, click on the alignment tab & then choose the number of degrees you want your oblique headings to be at); that will give it the slanted appearance that I think you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me! I'm in Excel 2k3

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me in Excel 2k3 until I unmerged my cells. Thanks for your help!